# Manually mount an external drive as user with full permissions

Tags: linux, arch-linux

How can I mount an external drive with read/write permissions for my user name?

I have tried mounting the drive in both `/mnt` and `~/mnt` through fstab, but neither gives `wdkrnls` write priviledge.

fstab:

> LABEL=500-hitachi /home/wdkrnls/mnt/500-hitachi ext4 defaults,users 0 1

How the drive is being mounted in my home directory via `ls -lah`:

```
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root  4.0K Oct  8 20:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 wdkrnls  users 4.0K Oct 14 14:14 ..
drwx------ 2 root     root   16K Oct  8 20:46 lost+found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `ext4` filesystem, permissions do not depend on mount options. (Although there was a proposed patch for that, but it was rejected.) You will have to use `chown` and/or `chmod` to give yourself write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to grawity's informative answer, you can use the `pmount` utility from extra to easily mount devices with `rw` permissions as a normal user.